# Calculating the partial sum of a expl3 sequence

Tags: expl3, xparse

How can I compute the partial sum of a sequence of integers? This is what I have so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc, forloop, xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_tmp_seq
\seq_new:N \g_partialsum_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_tmp_seq {3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1}

\newcounter{i}
\newcounter{j}
\newcounter{lengthplusone}
\setcounter{lengthplusone}{\seq_count:N \g_tmp_seq + 1}

\forloop{i}{1}{ \value{i} < \value{lengthplusone} }{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_partialsum_seq {0
    \forloop{j}{1}{ \value{j} < \value{i} }{
      + \seq_item:Nn \g_tmp_seq { \value{j} - 1}
    }
  }
}

\cs_new:Npn \partialsum #1 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_partialsum_seq { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\partialsum{1} % should be 0

\partialsum{2} % should be 3

\partialsum{3} % should be 4

\partialsum{4} % should be 6

\partialsum{5} % should be 10

\partialsum{6} % should be 10
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the sum doesn't get expanded, plus all the values of `\partialsum` are equal to the last summation.

Comment: `\partialsum{1} % should be 0`: Shouldn't it be 3 (_i.e.,_ the first item in the sequence)?

Comment: No, I need it to be `\partialsum{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \g_tmp_seq{i}` for `n > 1` and `\partialsum{1} = 0`.

Comment: @noibe I have been looking into the 51 questions you have been asking since last October (2018). What are you doing?

Comment: @KeksDose ahahah a little bit of everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more natural to use expl3 iteration over the seq I think:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_tmp_seq
\seq_new:N \g_partialsum_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_tmp_seq {3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1}
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_partialsum_seq {0}
\tl_new:N\l_sum

\seq_map_inline:Nn\g_tmp_seq{
  \tl_set:Nx\l_sum{\int_eval:n{\l_sum+#1}}
  \seq_gput_right:NV \g_partialsum_seq \l_sum
}

\NewDocumentCommand\partialsum {m}{
  \seq_item:Nn \g_partialsum_seq { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\partialsum{1} % should be 0

\partialsum{2} % should be 3

\partialsum{3} % should be 4

\partialsum{4} % should be 6

\partialsum{5} % should be 10

\partialsum{6} % should be 10
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I dropped `calc` and `forloop` entirely, as you can do everything using plain `expl3`. As a bonus you can make the command expandable and have an optional argument to set the starting point of the summation.

The major difference from your version is that the code doesn't store the summed sequence. Each time the command is used the summation is done for the selected interval.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_noibe_numbers_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \g_noibe_numbers_seq {3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \partialsum { O{1} m }
  { \__noibe_partialsum:Nnnn \g_noibe_numbers_seq {#1-2} {#2-2} { } }
\cs_new:Npn \__noibe_partialsum:Nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#2} > {#3}
      { \int_eval:n {#4 0} }
      {
        \exp_args:Nf
        \__noibe_partialsum:nN { \int_eval:n {#2+1} } #1
          {#4} {#3}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__noibe_partialsum:nN #1 #2
  {
    \exp_args:Nf
    \__noibe_partialsum:nnNnn { \seq_item:Nn #2 {#1} + } {#1} #2
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__noibe_partialsum:nnNnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
  { \__noibe_partialsum:Nnnn #3 {#2} {#5} {#4#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\partialsum{1} % should be 0

\partialsum{2} % should be 3

\partialsum{3} % should be 4

\partialsum{4} % should be 6

\partialsum{5} % should be 10

\partialsum{6} % should be 10

\ifnum\partialsum{5}=\partialsum{6}
  The fifth item is zero.
\else
  The fifth item is nonzero.
\fi
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Much less code with `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setsequence}{m}
 {% #1 = items
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_noibe_sequence_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\partialsum}{m}
 {% #1 = (one more than the) number of items to sum
  \int_eval:n
   { 
    0 \int_step_function:nN { #1 - 1 } \__noibe_sequence_sum:n
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__noibe_sequence_sum:n
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 > \seq_count:N \l_noibe_sequence_seq }
   {
    + \seq_item:Nn \l_noibe_sequence_seq { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setsequence{3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1}

\partialsum{1} --- should be 0

\partialsum{2} --- should be 3

\partialsum{3} --- should be 4

\partialsum{4} --- should be 6

\partialsum{5} --- should be 10

\partialsum{6} --- should be 10

\partialsum{7} --- should be 11

\partialsum{8} --- should be 11

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should the sequence be private?

Comment: @JosephWright Not necessarily, in my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough: I was musing rather than asking for a change